# Regex doesn't work with grep

Tags: awk, grep, regular-expression, busybox, ash

I have a string like this

```
TEST="/dev/sda1 on /media/sda1 type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0000,dmask=0000,allow_utime=0022,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,quiet)"
```

(Result from `mount | grep sda1`)

where I want to match the mount point. My regex ([adopted from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings)) is

`(?<=on[ \t])(.*)(?=[ \t]type)`

But for some reasons it doesn't work for me with several tools (Busybox ash 1.14.2):

`echo $TEST | grep -o -e '(?<=on[ \t])(.*)(?=[ \t]type)'`

Gives me no result.

`echo $TEST | awk 'match($0, /(?<=on )(.*)(?= type)/){print $0}'`

Returns an error `awk: bad regex '(?<=on[   ])(.*)(?=[  ]type)': Invalid preceding regular expression`

`expr match "$TEST" '\(?<=on[ \t]\)\(.*\)\(?=[ \t]type\)'`

Also returns an empty result.

I feel kinda stupid.

Comment: Why don't you just try to match `on (.*) type`?

Comment: Note also that if you want the third field of a line, awk can give it to you for free: `echo $TEST | awk '{print $3}'`.

Comment: AFAIK blank is also a valid character for an USB device so this would break this code. Otherwise I could use `echo $TEST | cut -d' ' -f3`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lookarounds are perl regex features. GNU grep implements them (with the `-P` option). I cannot say whether any busybox command does.

In this case though, you're just looking for the work after "on". Choose one of

```
echo "$TEST" | awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == "on") {print $(i+1); break}}'
echo "$TEST" | sed 's/.*on[[:blank:]]\(.*\)[[:blank:]]type.*/\1/'
```